# Regex for a-z, 0-9, . and -

Tags: regex

Can someone tell me what the syntax for a regex would be that would only allow the following characters:

- a-z (lower case only)
- 0-9
- period, dash, underscore

Additionally the string must start with only a lower case letter (a-z) and cannot contain any spaces or other characters than listed above.

Thank you in advance for the help,
Justin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do: `"^[a-z][-a-z0-9\._]*$"`

Here is the breakdown

- `^` beginning of line
- `[a-z]` character class for lower values, to match the first letter
- `[-a-z0-9\._]` character class for the rest of the required value
- `*` zero or more for the last class
- `$` end of String

Comment: this is wrong.  won't match dash, instead you have a range from dot to underscore.

Comment: When I use this regex with the following string: "test", I get this error: 
"preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found"
Any idea what this means?

Comment: `*` is zero or more repetitions, not one or more.

Comment: Justin: try putting slashes at the beginning and end of the string. eg: `"/^[a-z][a-z0-9\.\-_]*$/"`

Comment: What regex flavor requires you to escape `[.]`?

Comment: with that backslash it's ok.  did i miss it or was the answer edited?

Comment: The `.` and `-` inside `[]` doesn't need escaping, but it works either way. `[\.\-]` is the same as `[.-]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
[-._a-z0-9]
```

or

```
[-.[:lower:][:digit:]]
```

or ...

depends on *which* version of regular expressions you aim for.

Comment: I will be using this with preg_match in php.

Comment: then it's

    /^[a-z][-._a-z0-9]*$/

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9._\s-]*
```

Comment: this is wrong.  won't match dash, which must be either the first or last in the class to be taken literally.